# Text is readable in document photo

Tags: flutter, ocr

I'm developing an Flutter application where I have to validate if the document photo text is readable (at least in majority). I have been searching different packages and plugins no one is useful. All the packages related with my searching parse the text of the photo to string, but it's not what I need to do. Someone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ABBYY Mobile Web Capture, a fully cross-platform solution for OCR (this includes checking image readability). However, you would need to perform all platform integrations on your own. Pros: fast to run on a mobile device, does not require internet connection. Cons: a lot of coding. Might cost you months.

Alternatively, you can use ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK, which does the following:

1. You upload your image to ABBYY Cloud Server
2. Cloud Server recognizes it all
3. You check recognition confidence and count of non-alphanumeric characters (such as #, ^, &). If this exceeds a certain level (say, 20%), then you can be certain that the image is not so good.

Pros: 10-20 lines of code. Cons: Does not work without an Internet connection, requires a few seconds to post the data and get the result.